# Video runs locally but not on apache 2 server

Tags: 12.04, apache2, localhost, mime-type, html5

I have a simple html page in which i am running video using html5 tags, when i run that page using firefox it runs the page and video properly. But when i run this page by setting the apache server using localhost it doesn't run. What could be the issue, what settings are required.

This is the path of my 'local-host' :

"localhost/Ubuntu/index.html"

And the code of my index.html page is :

```
<img src="index.jpeg">

  <video controls preload="auto" loop>
        <source src="test.ogv" type="application/ogg; codecs="dirac, vorbis"" />
        <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"" />
    </video>

</div>
</form>
```

Should i have to set MIME type for apache server. I am new to linux so please give me code suggestions quickly.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the videos from the page source. I guess its a permission issue. You may need to change the file permission.

To do that, run this command in the folder: `chmod 755 test.*`

Comment: how to do that...

Comment: i think i need to set mime type for apache server..when i run my html page directly with firefox, it plays the video. But when i play the page through apache server setting the page in /var/www folder it doesn't play. Means there is some setting to do with apache server.